# How to make a pop up remain after a countdown?

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I have been developing a pop up div to show up after 60 seconds and I have had help with a kind person on here last week to help finish the code, as shown below:

```js
const startTime = new Date(),
  popup = document.getElementById("popup"),
  textPad = document.getElementById("text");

function showPopup() {
  const now = new Date(new Date() - startTime),
    minsLeft = now.getSeconds() % 60;

  if (minsLeft > 58) {
    popup.style.display = "inline-block";
    textPad.style.display = "none";
    setTimeout(showPopup, 60 * 1000); // Keeps message
  } else {
    popup.style.display = "none";
    textPad.style.display = "block";
    textPad.textContent = `${59 - minsLeft} second${minsLeft - 58 ? 's' : ''}`;
    setTimeout(showPopup, 1 * 1000); // Countdown
  }

}
showPopup();
```

```css
.outer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: red;
}

.inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
  color: red;
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div id="popup" class="inner">
    This is the pop-up.
  </div>
  <div id="text"></div>
</div>
```

I just wonder if any one would know how to make the red text on a white background ‘This is a pop up’ pop up div remain on the screen and not disappear after the 60 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

```
const startTime = new Date(),
popup = document.getElementById("popup"),
textPad = document.getElementById("text");


function showPopup() {
  const now = new Date(new Date() - startTime),
    minsLeft = now.getSeconds() % 10;
  
  if (minsLeft > 58) {
    popup.style.display = "block";
    textPad.style.display = "none";   
  } else {
    textPad.textContent = `${9 - minsLeft} minute${minsLeft - 8 ? 's' : ''} to wait`;   
     setTimeout(showPopup, 1 * 1000); // Redo on every minute
  }

}
showPopup();
```

This any good?

Comment: Sorry I have amended the code to a 60 second version, sorry

but would you say swap the none and block with the script below?

    popup.style.display = "none";
    textPad.style.display = "block";

Comment: @Timothy Ive amended mine to the 60 second version, if all you are wanting to do is have a pop up appear after 60 seconds and then stay on screen the above amendment should do that for you, so removing the popup.style.display = "none"; textPad.style.display = "block from your else will achieve this